# Can't start heroku locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Does someone know what is this error I am getting when I try to start heroku locally(after I write Heroku locally I get this error):

```
[WARN] No ENV file found
15:23:12 worker.1   |  C:\Users\Marija\Documents\Projects\project\node_modules\natural\lib\natural\brill_pos_tagger\lib    \Brill_POS_Tagger.js:26
15:23:12 worker.1   |  logger.setLevel('WARN');
15:23:12 worker.1   |         ^
15:23:12 worker.1   |  TypeError: logger.setLevel is not a function
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marija\Documents\Projects\project\node_modules\natural\lib    \natural\brill_pos_tagger\lib\Brill_POS_Tagger.js:26:8)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marija\Documents\Projects\project\node_modules\natural\lib    \natural\index.js:81:26)
15:23:12 worker.1   |      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
   [DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
   internal/util.js:183
  throw new errors.Error('ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL', signal);
  ^

Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL]: Unknown signal: null
   at convertToValidSignal (internal/util.js:183:9)
   at ChildProcess.kill (internal/child_process.js:381:5)
   at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marija\AppData\Local\heroku\client\node_modules\foreman\lib\proc.js:54:11)
   at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:7)
   at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marija\AppData\Local\heroku\client\node_modules\foreman\lib\proc.js:50:13)
   at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

Comment: Try run `heroku login`

Comment: I did. already logged in

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.  Just started happing in last few days.

Comment: I just found another thread - fixed the problem for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048784/heroku-open-puma-port-5000-already-in-use-rails

Comment: The problem is not the same @user670562

Answer (score 0):

1. On Windows, heroku has a different Procfile and the command is `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows`
2. The first line says `No ENV file found`. Check the project folder if there is an `.env` file there or not. If it's missing that is causing the error.